# data frame select expression inside withcolumn

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a data frame with adding a column using case statement. Below is code snippet.

```
orders=ordDtConvDF.withColumn('Status',\
ordDtConvDF.selectExpr('case 
when order_status in ("CLOSED","COMPLETE") then "completed" \
when order_status="PENDING_PAYMENT" then "Pending" \
else "Processing/canceled" end' ) )
```

Its giving an error as below. Appreciate your help.

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-e633b3a604b9> in <module>
----> 1 orders=ordDtConvDF.withColumn('Status',ordDtConvDF.selectExpr('case when order_status in ("CLOSED","COMPLETE") then "completed" \
      2                              when order_status="PENDING_PAYMENT" then "Pending" \
      3                        else "Processing/canceled" end' ) )

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in withColumn(self, colName, col)
   2452 
   2453         """
-> 2454         assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"
   2455         return DataFrame(self._jdf.withColumn(colName, col._jc), self.sql_ctx)
   2456 

AssertionError: col should be Column
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of `selectExpr`

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

orders = (ordDtConvDF.withColumn('Status', F
    .when(F.col('order_status').isin('CLOSED', 'COMPLETE'), 'completed')
    .when(F.col('order_status').isin('PENDING_PAYMENT'), 'Pending')
    .otherwise('Processing/canceled')
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `F.expr` instead of `selectExpr`:

```
orders = ordDtConvDF.withColumn(
    'Status',
    F.expr("""
        case when order_status in ("CLOSED","COMPLETE") then "completed"
             when order_status = "PENDING_PAYMENT" then "Pending"
             else "Processing/canceled" 
        end
    """ 
    ) 
)
```